# SWIFT: Parsing a JSON Object

Tags: ios, json, swift

first post here!

I've been working on my own weather application (I'm a high school student who's self-learning Swift, but already have experience in Java).

I'm learning how to use API's to gather information to use in my application and I've been using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-LZs0De7_U

At around the 11:38 mark, a JSON object is created:

```
    var jsonError: NSError
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary

    if let name = json["name"] as? String {
        cityNameLabel.text = name
    }

    if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
            cityTemperatureLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", arguments: temp)
        }
```

Basically I want to parse a String out of the JSON object and have my UILabel store the String.

However, the second line of code gives me an error saying: 'NSError is not identical to NSError?' and I couldn't find a solution to this error, so I got rid of the first two lines and replaced them with:

```
    var jsonError : NSError?

    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: nil, error: &jsonError)


    if let error = jsonError{
        println("error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else if let jsonDict = json as? NSDictionary{
        println("json is dictionary \(jsonDict)")
    }
    else if let jsonArray = json as? NSArray{
        println("json is an array: \(jsonArray)")
    }
```

This got rid of the error but the rest of the code didn't work anymore. Any possible solutions + explanations? I am still new to API's/JSON so apologies if I am not explaining my problem well. 
The video should be able to help you guys help me!

EDIT: Apparently I am using Swift version 1.2

Comment: var jsonError: NSError? = nil

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Can you elaborate?

Comment: Change your first line to how I showed. Tell me if that works!

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I did, and unfortunately I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: Add a do catch loop for swift 2 like the answer shown below. That ought to work.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I posted down below on CodeBender's reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome. Looks like you have old Swift code that is no longer valid. This should hopefully work.

```
    var json: AnyObject?

    do {
       try json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    if let name = json["name"] as? String {
        cityNameLabel.text = name
    }

    if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
            cityTemperatureLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", arguments: temp)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for you response. I copied over your code but I'm still getting errors. i.e. 'consecutive statements must be separated by ';' (for the try statement) which doesn't seem to make sense... and the catch is giving me an error saying 'computed property must have an explicit type' the if let statements are also giving me a 'could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments'

Comment: @JustinHu `I'm still getting errors` Because this code is for Swift 2 and you're using Swift 1.

Comment: hey, I just updated Swift and happy to say that your code works! Thanks man

Comment: Cool. Just as an FYI, Swift is undergoing a lot of changes, so be careful of any tutorials / answers you see that are more than six months old, since a lot of breaking changes have been made. Plus, more on coming with Swift 3.0 due later this year. :)